# Sharing files between 2 Ubuntu One accounts

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have Ubuntu-One both at work and at home, and would like to share files between the two. However, these are set up under two different Ubuntu-One accounts, with different logins and passwords; I'd like to integrate both accounts into one, with the same login/password, so that files can be shared/synced between the two. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

On the machine you wish to change open ubuntuone navigate to the Devices tab and remove that machine. close ubuntuone, reopen it and sign in with the info from the other machine. Then you simply have to select the cloud folders you wish  to sync.